# Why am I having issues with my flutter firebase authentification?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

My goal is to sign in with an existing account on my firebase data and show exceptions when the account is not existing... I followed some tutorials and the official firebase and flutter documentation. When I'm trying to log with an not existing or existing account the button login to naviguate in the home screen doesn't work.

**Plus I have this error message `type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'TextEditingController' in type cast`**

I have two pages code for this function

First my code in auth Provider Service Screen :

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class AuthClass {
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  Future<String?> signIN({required String email, required String password}) async {
    try {
      await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email,
          password: password,);
      return "Welcome";
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
        return 'No user found for that email.';
      } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
        return 'Wrong password provided for that user.';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and this is my body login screen code:

```
import 'package:yona/WelcomePage/WelcomePage.dart';

class Body extends StatefulWidget {
  const Body({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _BodyState createState() => _BodyState();
}

class _BodyState extends State<Body> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey  = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  TextEditingController _email = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _password = TextEditingController();


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery
        .of(context)
        .size;
    return Background(
        child: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
        Text("LOGIN", style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontSize: 20)),
          Container(child: Image.asset('assets/ctlogo.png', height: 200),
          ),
       // Container
        RoundedInputField(
            hintText: "Your Email",
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                _email = value.trim() as TextEditingController;
              });
            }
        ),
        RoundedPasswordField(
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              _password = value.trim() as TextEditingController;
            });
          },
        ),
        Container(margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
          width: 300,
          child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(29),
            // ignore: deprecated_member_use
            child: FlatButton(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 14, horizontal: 40),
              color: SandYellow,
              onPressed: () {
                AuthClass()
                    .signIN(
                    email: _email.text.trim(), password: _password.text.trim())
                    .then((value) {
                  if (value == 'Welcome') {
                    Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => HomeScreen()),
                      (route) => false);
                    }
                  else{
                    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(value!)));
                  }
                  }
                );
              },
              child: Text("LOGIN",
                  style: TextStyle(color: DarkTurquoise,
                    fontSize: 16,)
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
value.trim() as TextEditingController;
```

value is already String so you can not type cast to TextEditingController.
_email variable should be a String in that way.

You can just delete `as TextEditingController` this part. so It will be worked.

Edit:

```
TextEditingController _email = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController _password = TextEditingController();
```

these variables should not be a Controller, should be a String.

```
String _email = '';
String _password = '';
```

Comment: **I deleted but I have still errors**:  "Error: A value of type 'String' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'TextEditingController'.
 - 'TextEditingController' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/editable_text.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/editable_text.dart').
                _email = value.trim();"  **Flutter suggested me to add cast to resolve my errors that's the reason why I add** "as TextEditingController"

Comment: you should delete all  'as TextEditingController'

Comment: I updated my answer. you should remove 'as TextEditingController' these part also.

Answer (score 0):

No need to `setState` when changing `TextEditingController` value.

```dart
onChanged: (value) {
  _email.text = value.trim();
}),
```

Comment: Thank you I removed Indeed it was useless but it didn't resolve my problems

Comment: @flomitri , What's the error you got after adding the code in my answer?